# Como usar um mesmo background para um elemento em forma de "X" com css e html?

Tags: css, html5

Eu criei um elemento em forma de "X" onde em cada extremidade eu quero usar um mesmo background. O background irá aparecer somente nas áreas em vermelho. Já tentei usar background-clip mas não consegui e não sei se é a forma correta. Segue uma imagem de como gostaria e o html e css de onde parei.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML e CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/wes_bp/58ozu6kq/

código do link

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.shape-group{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

ul,
li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.section-be-four ul.x-shape{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background: url(/assets/img/about1.jpg);
}

.section-be-four li{
    position: absolute;
    width: 311px;
    height: 411px;
    background: blue;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: .5s;
}

.section-be-four .shape-1{
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.section-be-four .shape-1::before{
    content: "";
}

.section-be-four .shape-2{
    top: 0;
    left: 63%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.section-be-four .shape-3{
    background: yellow;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 311px;
    top: 38.5%;
    left: 31.5%;
}
.section-be-four .shape-4{
    top: 63%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.section-be-four .shape-5{
    top: 63%;
    left: 63%;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-be-four section-four">
    <div class="col-full">
        <div class="shape-group">
            <ul class="x-shape">
                <li class="shape shape-1"><div class="shape-bg-1"></div></li>
                <li class="shape shape-2"><div class="shape-bg-2"></div></li>
                <li class="shape shape-3"><div class="shape-bg-3"></div></li>
                <li class="shape shape-4"><div class="shape-bg-4"></div></li>
                <li class="shape shape-5"><div class="shape-bg-5"></div></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara para que complicar... cria um `svg` com os `shapes`, coloca o `svg` dentro de uma `div` com a imagem de `background`, depois dentro dessa `div` use elementos com `position absolute` para escreve e alinha o texto.

Vc vai ver que não usa quase nada de código, e a imagem eu usei como `background-image` da div para não complicar fazendo um `patter/fill` no `svg` etc. então é fácil trocar a imagem e a cor vermelha vc pode trocar em `HEX` no `fill` do segundo `path` `fill="#FF0000"` do `svg`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
.imagem {
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/500/500);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.imagem  svg {
  display: block;
}
.imagem .texto {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}
.texto.tl {
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
}
.texto.tr {
  top: 150px;
  right: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagem">
  <svg width="800" height="800" viewBox="0 0 800 800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="800" height="800" fill="none"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M800 0H0V160V800H160H640H800L800 160L800 0ZM560 400L800 160L640 0.000167847L400 240L160 0.000172477L0 160L240 400L0.000140592 640L160 800L400 560L640 800L800 640L560 400Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M800 160L640 0.000167847L400 240L160 0.000172477L0 160L240 400L0.000140592 640L160 800L400 560L640 800L800 640L560 400L800 160ZM560 400L400 240L240 400L400 560L560 400Z" fill="#FF0000" fill-opacity="0.28"/>
  </svg>
  <span class="texto tl">texto 1</span>
  <span class="texto tr">texto 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Já que é pra simplificar, tira esse text-shadow feioso rsrsrs. +1 pela solução enxuta mesmo assim.

Comment: @bfavaretto hahaha é pq eu queria garantir o contraste do texto já que não da para saber a imagem que vem do CDN... Mas isso é ao gosto do cliente, pode até usar Comic Sans se quiser  

Comment: Valeu @hugocsl me ajudou D+ ! Por hora vou apenas fazer um copy/paste do que você fez pra adiantar o trampo aqui, mas gostaria de saber se você usou alguma ferramenta para fazer o svg se sim qual ? Abç!

Comment: @wbp que bom que já ajudou ai. Usei o Figma, é de graça e roda no browser, vc desenha lá e já exporta como SVG, que por sinal o SVG exportado por ele é de ótima qualidade de código, bem limpo!

Comment: Valeu mais uma vez @hugocsl! Abraço!

Answer (score -1):

Crie uma `div` grande onde colocará a imagem. Logo após crie as demais `divs` que ficarão em vermelho, adicione uma `opacity` nelas e um rotation. As partes em branco também devem ser uma `div` onde você colocará `backgroun-color: white` sem `opacity`. Não sei se conseguiu me entender, mas seria apenas um "jogo" de pequenos elementos em cima do elemento principal que irá conter um `background` com a imagem que você escolheu.